# I cannot use pylint in VSC using pipenv & bash for windows 10

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, pylint, pipenv

While proceeding Django Project Now, I'm having trouble with linter in VSC, pylint. First I'm using virtual environments with pipenv. and I'm using Visual Studio Code Version 1.19.1 with Windows 10. The trouble that I'm having is even though I installed pylint with pipenv and pip commands, VSC can't recognize it and Installation with Visual Studio Code can't work [image][image]

First I figured out that python path settings pointed global setting, not virtual envs. so I edit settings.json for VSC like following way.

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\seungjinlee\\AppData\\Local\\lxss\\home\\seungjinlee\\.local\\share\\virtualenvs\\seungjingram-6b3oTnkI\\bin\\python",
}
```

from [image]
  but It didn't work as well. 
  [image]
  [image]

Is it problem with bash for windows? I guess bash shell create virtual enviorments for Ubuntu. but I'm using editor VSC with windows 10 so it can't find pylint for windows,.,.,, plz help me..!

Comment: I faced the same problem on Mac OS.

Comment: I found out that there is no `pylint` installed inside virtual environment directory. Could you check your's?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on Mac OS. I solved it with the next sequence:

```sh
$ cd project_directory
$ pipenv install pylint
$ code .
```

So, the thing is to run VS Code from command line with activated virtual environment. I'm not sure if it helps for Windows, though.

For Windows a workaround may be to specify exact path to pylint in workspace settings:

```
"python.linting.pylintPath": "C:\\Users\\seungjinlee\\AppData\\Local\\lxss\\home\\seungji‌​nlee\\.local\\share\‌​\virtualenvs\\seungj‌​ingram-6b3oTnkI\\bin‌​\\pylint"
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer :) But It doesn't work, though.. :<  I think the problem is VSC is for windows but pylint and virtual env is for Linux(Ubuntu bash shell for windows 10) so the difference makes problem :< I can find pylint for my lxss directory but it still doesn't work

Comment: You also can try to specify exact path to pylint in workspace settings: `"python.linting.pylintPath": "C:\\Users\\seungjinlee\\AppData\\Local\\lxss\\home\\seungjinlee\\.local\\share\\virtualenvs\\seungjingram-6b3oTnkI\\bin\\pylint"`.

Comment: The Python extension for VS Code does not officially support WSL, so if you're using it then that could be the problem here.

Comment: I’m on macOS and I also had to specify `python.linting.pylintPath` for this to work.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was:

1. Making sure VS Code was using the correct virtual environment by running `Python: Select Interpreter` from the command palette (`Ctrl+Shift+P`) and choosing the correct option (it should detect your virtual environment and suggest it, but if not, try setting `python.pythonPath` as some as suggested, as well as `python.venvFolders` and/or `python.venvPath`. Also maybe try creating your virtual environment in the same folder as your project)
2. Running `Python: Select Linter` from the command palette and choosing pylint.
3. And then I still have to sometimes change a character and then save to make it start linting.

Hope this helps.